# Why does demand curve shift in, in a monopolistic competitive market?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand, monopoly, competition, monopolistic-competition

In a monopolistic competitive market, demand curves shift in, if more firms enter the market. I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Demand remains the same, supply has increased. Shouldn't entry of more firms change the supply curve, rather than demand curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demand for *existing* firms' product shifts in because the entering firms attract some of the users.